# Maatwebsite 3.1 import, Queue does not work

Tags: laravel-5.7, maatwebsite-excel

My file is *excel .xlsx* contains more than *20,000 rows*, im using *Centos 7* with *Nginx web server*. When i upload a small size file with few rows it works but when i introduce *ShouldQueue* and *WithChunkReading* interfaces it fails even if the file is small. Please I need help. Thanks for your time

> Here is the error in a log file

```
 vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php  
[2019-07-11 14:48:47] development.ERROR: [0] File "/tmp/laravel-excel-4noteGu1gFjJoFClKJQsLw8SgDShm1nd.xlsx" does not exist. on line 344 of file vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php  
[2019-07-11 14:48:47] development.ERROR: [0] File "/tmp/laravel-excel-4noteGu1gFjJoFClKJQsLw8SgDShm1nd.xlsx" does not exist. on line 344 of file vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php
```

> Here is a queue error

```
    [2019-07-12 10:11:47][532] Processing: Maatwebsite\Excel\Jobs\QueueImport
[2019-07-12 10:11:47][532] Processed:  Maatwebsite\Excel\Jobs\QueueImport
[2019-07-12 10:11:47][533] Processing: Maatwebsite\Excel\Jobs\ReadChunk
[2019-07-12 10:11:47][534] Processing: Maatwebsite\Excel\Jobs\ReadChunk
[2019-07-12 10:11:47][535] Processing: Maatwebsite\Excel\Jobs\ReadChunk
[2019-07-12 10:11:47][535] Failed:     Maatwebsite\Excel\Jobs\ReadChunk
```

> **Here is my controller function**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     Excel::import(new HsCodeImport(),"650.xlsx",'local'); 
     return redirect()->back()->withFlashSuccess(__('label.app_success'));
}
```

> Here is my Import file on App\Imports\HsCodeImport.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Exceptions\GeneralException;
use App\Models\Application\Hscode;
use App\Models\ReceiptCode\ReceiptCode;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithBatchInserts;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;

class HsCodeImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow, ShouldQueue, WithChunkReading
{
    use Importable;

    protected $receiptCode;
    protected $chunk = 500;
    protected $hscode_key = 'hscode';
    protected $description_key = 'description';
    protected $regulatory_status_key = 'regulatory_status';
    protected $comment_key = 'comment';
    protected $headings = ['hscode','description','regulatory_status','comment'];

    public function __construct(/*ReceiptCode $receiptCode*/)
    {
//        $this->receiptCode = $receiptCode;
    }

    /**
     * @param Collection $collection
     * @throws GeneralException
     */
    public function collection(Collection $collection)
    {
        /*fetching the first Collection*/
        $columns = $collection->first();

        if (!$columns->has($this->headings)) {
            /*When file has different headings*/

        } else {
            /*When the file has expected headings*/

            /*Truncate temp table*/
            DB::table('hs_code_temps')->truncate();

            /*Counting rows on a file*/
            $original_file_rows_count = $collection->count();


            /*Chunk the file data according @var $chunk*/
            $chunks = $collection->chunk($this->chunk);

            /*read each chunks insert into Temporary table and validate to get if there is error in each row*/
            $chunks->each(function ($item) {
                /*Iterate on each chunk*/
                $item->toArray();

                foreach ($item as $row) {

                    /* start: Validating row entries */
                    $error_report = "";
                    $error = 0;

                    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                        if (trim($key) == $this->hscode_key) {
                            if (trim($value) == "" Or $value == NULL) {
                                $error = 1;
                                $error_report = $error_report . trans('exceptions.backend.upload.entries', ['column' => $key, 'entry' => $value]) . ", \r\n";
                                $row[$key] = NULL;
                            }
                        } elseif (trim($key) == $this->description_key) {
                            if (trim($value) == "" Or $value == NULL) {
                                $error = 1;
                                $error_report = $error_report . trans('exceptions.backend.upload.entries', ['column' => $key, 'entry' => $value]) . ", \r\n";
                                $row[$key] = NULL;
                            }
                        } elseif (trim($key) == $this->regulatory_status_key) {
                            if (trim($value) == "" Or $value == NULL) {
                                $error = 1;
                                $error_report = $error_report . trans('exceptions.backend.upload.entries', ['column' => $key, 'entry' => $value]) . ", \r\n";
                                $row[$key] = NULL;
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    /*Inserting into Temp table*/
                    DB::table('hs_code_temps')->insert([
                        'code' => $row[$this->hscode_key],
                        $this->description_key => $row[$this->description_key],
                        $this->regulatory_status_key => $row[$this->regulatory_status_key],
                        $this->comment_key => $row[$this->comment_key],
                        'receipt_code_id' => 1/*$receiptCode->id*/,
                        'error' => $error,
                        'error_report' => $error_report,
                        'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                        ]);

                    /* end: Validating row entries*/

                }

            });

            /*compare total rows with no error to total rows of the file*/
            $total_temp_rows_count = DB::table('hs_code_temps')->whereError(0)->count();

            if ($total_temp_rows_count != $original_file_rows_count) {
                /*When there is error and rows are not equal*/
            } else {
                /*When there is no error*/
                $originalHsCode = new Hscode();
                $temp_table = DB::table('hs_code_temps')->get(['code', $this->description_key, $this->regulatory_status_key, $this->comment_key])/*->toArray()*/;
                /*Iterate throw the rows in a temp row*/
                foreach ($temp_table as $object) {
                    /*copy data from temp table to origin table*/
                    $originalHsCode->create(get_object_vars($object));
                }
                /*Truncate temp table*/
                DB::table('hs_code_temps')->truncate();

            }


        }


    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return ['HSCode','Description','Regulatory_Status','Comment'];
    }

    /*public function sheets(): array
    {

    }*/

    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 500;
    }

    public function batchSize(): int
    {
        return 500;
    }

}
```

I expect the job to run a large data to a chunk to be processed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass false as third parameter to chunk() to disable queuing

```
$data = [];
Excel::filter('chunk')->load($path)->chunk(1000, function ($results) use (&$data) {
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}, $shouldQueue = false);
return $data;
```

Comment: If someone can explain why when $shouldQueue = true even when passing by reference (&$data) the variable can't be changed inside the callback?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem when deplying to heroku ,that points to a problem with the path.:

```
`ERROR: [0] File "/tmp/laravel-excel-4noteGu1gFjJoFClKJQsLw8SgDShm1nd.xlsx" 
does not exist. on line 344 of file 
vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php`
```

laravel-excel defines local_path variable in config/excel.php, so try changing the path here or check your public_path() where you are geting the problem.

in my case the excemption saved in table failde_jobs is:

`"exception": """ InvalidArgumentException: File "/app/storage/framework/laravel-excel/laravel-excel-aCnUQTJT7ADvAnrf1AOEcaCBPLjhauij" does not exist. in /app/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Shared/File.php:135\n`

have been trying to see how to change sot that it does not go in the app folder..